# Fluent NHibernate references and legacy database

Tags: nhibernate, reference, fluent, legacy

I have an entity

```
public class classA
{
public virtual classAId id {get;set;}
}
```

It has a compositeId

```
public class classAId 
{
public virtual int a {get;set;}
public virtual int b {get;set;}
}
```

classB references classA

```
public class classB
{
public virtual classA ref {get;set;}
}
```

The database table for classB has only **one** column for the reference ref, the other column (for the compositeId of the reference which is classA) is retrieved from the program and is not persisted in the database, nor can I persist it in the database (normally it is 0 for instance).

So how can I implement the reference in classB so that it retrieves and saves an instance of classA correctly without persisting the additional column in the database?

**Edit:** or can I somehow filter classA on the column in question first, so that classA then has only a 1 column key?

Answer (score 0):

in xml you can use a formula

```
<many-to-one>
    <column name="a" />
    <formula text="('foo')" />
</many-to-one>
```